# Flutter App having performance issues after playstore push

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-design

I am beginner at flutter development.Completed my first app and also pushed to playstore.But after downloading the the app each click take more time to get the response and also the UI is incomplete.How can i find out the isuues with my app?
For each click its takes around 20 seconds  respond
In my app using number picker dialog it popup after 20 seconds delay

Steps followed :

1. Tested with apk in numerous emulators and found no issues
2. tested in local android phone and found no issues
3. released in play store with .aab format and performance issue pops up
   Thanks in adavance

Comment: You need to provide more details like screen shots for example. But have you not tested the release version of the app on a real device before release? Have you tested it on multiple different screen sizes to check for responsiveness and overflow issues?

Comment: Yes we are tested in different real devices it's working perfectly.But after the playstore push each click in the screen take more time to get response